# Filter data in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, filter

i am trying to filter out the data that i want, and hide all the other data instead.
 Here is my list of code,

```
private void searchButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
            bs.Filter = dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" +  searchTextBox.Text + "%'";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

        }
```

but when i run it, it prompts me error message

"Missing operand after 'ID' operator."

and i have tried this too, same error message.

```
private void searchButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
           // bs.Filter = dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + searchTextBox.Text + "%'";
            bs.Filter = "Sample ID like '*" + searchTextBox.Text + "*'";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        }
```

can anyone please help me clarify the problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following ,

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = "yourColumnName like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

or

In Search Text Box Changed event, try the following,

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", searchTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: the first code still gives me the same error, but the second one gives me this instead

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." , btw my Sample ID column's data consists of both alphabetical letter and number.

Comment: It may be because of have space between Sample and ID, can you try for some other column, just to find the cause

Comment: I have fix the problem by changing the "Sample ID" to "SampleID" from the database, and it worked, but it doesn't make sense because even in the coding, i have include the space in between...

Comment: Problem is C# cannot parse the space in expressions. Im not sure if putting [] for the column name which has space could help

Comment: oh, i shall research on that on my own for more information. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2837847:: I try this code. when i put a letter in the text box if it present in datagridview then it gives the out put but when the letter is absent then it shows an error.  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." what i do?

Comment: @AnimeshGhosh check if your database's header has no space in between the words and change accordingly. That's one of the error i've fix while working on this code, i'm not sure why c# wasn't good with spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Try with following

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = "[HeaderText] Like '%" + searchTextBox.Text + "%'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Answer (score 1):

I set my datasource as list and used LINQ to filter the datagridview.

```
//Declare Global
List<ProductList> _productList

//Somewhere in code initialize datagridview
DataGridView1.DataSource = _productList

//TextBox TextChanged Function
private void TxtSearchProduct_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var result = _productList.Where(x => 
   x.ProductName.Contains(TxtSearchProduct.Text)).ToList();
   DataGridView1.DataSource = result;
}
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 approach in this subject:

1 If you are using data table

```
bsItems.Filter = "VendorAccount like'*" + txtFilterAccount.Text + "*'";
```

2 Using ORM like dapper
you will have to create new list to stored filtered data

```
lstFilteredVendors = lstVendors.Where(x => x.VendorAccount.Contains(t.Text)).ToList();
                    bsItems.DataSource = lstFilteredVendors;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) 
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
            }
            else if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
            }
            else if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide some informations to your code? For example how it answers the question?